# How to render a template without display

Tags: php, twig

I try to find a way in order to send all HTML code generated by a twig template
in variable without displaying this one like that :

```
$var = $twig->render('pages/exports/exportLayout.html.twig'....
```

Is there a solution for disable display and just have the result in variable ?
Please note that I don't use symfony but only twig template in PHP.
Thx

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can with the code you just wrote:
`$twig->render('index.html', array('the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here'));`

API says: "Return Value: string (The rendered template)"

Just don't echo it.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried this at first time and it didn't worked :'(

Edit : and now it works... sorry btw thx a lot for your answer, so simple...

Comment: Can you post some more code maybe? Should work like that

Comment: It works now, thx a lot, I surely have made a mistake last time, sorry :)